# how to configure multiples logging in jMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to do performance testing where my scenario is 100 different user logging per day

Comment: Please give more details/example (I didn't downvoted)

Comment: Please have a read here: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as this is way to vague and answered multiple times. So search first!

Comment: @RayOei If there is a question that this is a duplicate of, please flag it as such

Comment: I tried to edit it to make more readable, but it's really impossible to understand what you want. And honestly, if you want someone to spend time answering your question, maybe you should spend more time editing your question, so it's readable and clear.

Comment: i have edited the scenario @KirilS. & user7294900

Comment: @Machavity who says I didn't? And in this case I don't feel I need to look for examples to show that this is even covered in the Jmeter manual. C'mon....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any performance testing for 100 users as 100 users per day = 12 users per hour = one user each 5 minutes, any server will handle this "load", even if it is running on a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/).

In general if at some point of time you would like to know the limits of your application, i.e. what is the maximum amount of users it can handle - you will need to go for so called [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) when you start with 1 user and gradually increase the load until response time starts exceeding acceptable thresholds or errors start occurring or website crashes whatever comes the first.

When it comes to using JMeter for web applications performance testing normally steps look like:

1. Record your test scenario(s) using [JMeter's Proxy Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
2. Perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) if required (most probably you will need it as modern web applications widely use dynamic parameters for i.e. user state management or [CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)))
3. Given your test assumes > 1 virtual user you should be using different credentials for every user. Most often JMeter users go for [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read the data from external file.

References:

- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#building)
- [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)

There is also an example test script available via `File -> Templates -> Building an Advanced Web Test Plan` entry of the JMeter main menu which you can use as a "skeleton" for your test

[image: JMeter web test plan]

Comment: I don't think it is improving stack if we/you are answering all bad questions as well. This could have been solved by OP by just doing _some_ research, for instance start reading the Jmeter docs. There are some expectations on what people do/have done when/before posting questions....